# Binding to an image in IsolatedStorage

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, viewmodel

Is it possible to data bind to an image in isolated storage without code behind or a converter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At some point, you need to open a stream, assign it to a BitmapImage and reference this on your Image control. So no direct means without writing code or using someone elses.